# How to get the current datetime in UTC from an Excel VBA macro

Tags: datetime, excel, timezone, vba

Is there a way in an Excel VBA macro to get the current datetime in UTC format?

I can call `Now()` to get the current time in the local timezone; is there a generic way to then convert this to UTC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002185_Automatically_Converting_to_GMT.html

There is a macro on that page with a LocalTimeToUTC method.  Looks like it would do the trick.  Also some formula examples if you wanted to go that route.

Edit - Another link.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx  This page has several methods for date/time.  Pick your poison.  Either should do the trick, but I feel like the second is prettier.  ;)

Comment: Ugh, both use Windows API calls, but if that's the only way then, then so be it. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Simply, you can use COM Object to achieve UTC Time Information.

```
Dim dt As Object, utc As Date
Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
dt.SetVarDate Now
utc = dt.GetVarDate(False)
```

Comment: That's great! Will this factor DST?? @gogeek

Comment: @MeenakshiSundharam UTC doesn't have DST but, given the current local time you can figure out the current timezone offset (including DST)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's efficient and short, just as code should be.

Comment: Excellent code.  Just want to mention that "Now" can be replaced with any date variable with date and time, so it doesn't need to be the current time.  It will convert any date and time to UTC.  Bravo gogeek.

Answer (score 8):

Granted this question is old, but I just spent some time putting together some clean code based on this and I wanted to post it here in case anyone coming across this page might find it useful.

Create a new Module in the Excel VBA IDE (optionally giving it a name of `UtcConverter` or whatever your preference may be in the Properties Sheet) and paste in the code below.

HTH

```
Option Explicit

' Use the PtrSafe attribute for x64 installations
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FileTimeToLocalFileTime Lib "Kernel32" (lpFileTime As FILETIME, ByRef lpLocalFileTime As FILETIME) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function LocalFileTimeToFileTime Lib "Kernel32" (lpLocalFileTime As FILETIME, ByRef lpFileTime As FILETIME) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SystemTimeToFileTime Lib "Kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME, ByRef lpFileTime As FILETIME) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib "Kernel32" (lpFileTime As FILETIME, ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Long

Public Type FILETIME
  LowDateTime As Long
  HighDateTime As Long
End Type

Public Type SYSTEMTIME
  Year As Integer
  Month As Integer
  DayOfWeek As Integer
  Day As Integer
  Hour As Integer
  Minute As Integer
  Second As Integer
  Milliseconds As Integer
End Type


'===============================================================================
' Convert local time to UTC
'===============================================================================
Public Function UTCTIME(LocalTime As Date) As Date
  Dim oLocalFileTime As FILETIME
  Dim oUtcFileTime As FILETIME
  Dim oSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME

  ' Convert to a SYSTEMTIME
  oSystemTime = DateToSystemTime(LocalTime)

  ' 1. Convert to a FILETIME
  ' 2. Convert to UTC time
  ' 3. Convert to a SYSTEMTIME
  Call SystemTimeToFileTime(oSystemTime, oLocalFileTime)
  Call LocalFileTimeToFileTime(oLocalFileTime, oUtcFileTime)
  Call FileTimeToSystemTime(oUtcFileTime, oSystemTime)

  ' Convert to a Date
  UTCTIME = SystemTimeToDate(oSystemTime)
End Function



'===============================================================================
' Convert UTC to local time
'===============================================================================
Public Function LOCALTIME(UtcTime As Date) As Date
  Dim oLocalFileTime As FILETIME
  Dim oUtcFileTime As FILETIME
  Dim oSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME

  ' Convert to a SYSTEMTIME.
  oSystemTime = DateToSystemTime(UtcTime)

  ' 1. Convert to a FILETIME
  ' 2. Convert to local time
  ' 3. Convert to a SYSTEMTIME
  Call SystemTimeToFileTime(oSystemTime, oUtcFileTime)
  Call FileTimeToLocalFileTime(oUtcFileTime, oLocalFileTime)
  Call FileTimeToSystemTime(oLocalFileTime, oSystemTime)

  ' Convert to a Date
  LOCALTIME = SystemTimeToDate(oSystemTime)
End Function



'===============================================================================
' Convert a Date to a SYSTEMTIME
'===============================================================================
Private Function DateToSystemTime(Value As Date) As SYSTEMTIME
  With DateToSystemTime
    .Year = Year(Value)
    .Month = Month(Value)
    .Day = Day(Value)
    .Hour = Hour(Value)
    .Minute = Minute(Value)
    .Second = Second(Value)
  End With
End Function



'===============================================================================
' Convert a SYSTEMTIME to a Date
'===============================================================================
Private Function SystemTimeToDate(Value As SYSTEMTIME) As Date
  With Value
    SystemTimeToDate = _
      DateSerial(.Year, .Month, .Day) + _
      TimeSerial(.Hour, .Minute, .Second)
  End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is the current time, you can do this with [GetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390%28VS.85%29.aspx), which involves fewer Win32 calls. It gives you a time struct, with millisecond precision, which you can format how you'd like:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Private Type SYSTEMTIME
  wYear As Integer
  wMonth As Integer
  wDayOfWeek As Integer
  wDay As Integer
  wHour As Integer
  wMinute As Integer
  wSecond As Integer
  wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type
```

Usage:

```
Dim nowUtc As SYSTEMTIME
Call GetSystemTime(nowUtc) 
' nowUtc is now populated with the current UTC time. Format or convert to Date as needed.
```

Comment: direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh. The question is about Excel VBA, NOT about "Excel VBA **for Windows**".
In short, none of the answers, however upvoted they may be, works on a Mac or on Linux (yes, Office, at least Office 2000, runs on Linux too)

So here is my answer. It's predictible it gets zero vote, but truth is not a beauty contest.

For Windows, see the other answers (those that silently **assume** Windows, demonstrating how programmers create problems by assuming things).

For the Mac, see https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=41117.

For Linux, see [How do I get GMT time in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449435/how-do-i-get-gmt-time-in-unix)

Have fun with VBA. Sorry to be so dry, but there's so much approximation going arround, S.O. gets scary now.

Comment: Please provide links that have anything to do with Excel or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to account for daylight saving time, you may find the following code useful:

```
Option Explicit

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Windows API Structures
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Type SYSTEM_TIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Type TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As SYSTEM_TIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As SYSTEM_TIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type    

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Windows API Imports
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" _
    (lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare Function TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime Lib "kernel32" _
    (lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, lpLocalTime As SYSTEM_TIME, lpUniversalTime As SYSTEM_TIME) As Integer

Function ToUniversalTime(localTime As Date) As Date
    Dim timeZoneInfo As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION

    GetTimeZoneInformation timeZoneInfo

    Dim localSystemTime As SYSTEM_TIME
    With localSystemTime
        .wYear = Year(localTime)
        .wMonth = Month(localTime)
        .wDay = Day(localTime)
    End With

    Dim utcSystemTime As SYSTEM_TIME

    If TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(timeZoneInfo, localSystemTime, utcSystemTime) <> 0 Then
        ToUniversalTime = SystemTimeToVBTime(utcSystemTime)
    Else
        err.Raise 1, "WINAPI", "Windows API call failed"
    End If

End Function

Private Function SystemTimeToVBTime(systemTime As SYSTEM_TIME) As Date
    With systemTime
        SystemTimeToVBTime = DateSerial(.wYear, .wMonth, .wDay) + _
                TimeSerial(.wHour, .wMinute, .wSecond)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My Access project works with mostly Access tables linked to MS SQL Server tables. It is a DAO project and I was having trouble even getting a SQL sproc with GETUTCDATE() to come back. But following was my solution.

```
-- Create SQL table with calculated field for UTCDate
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUTCDate](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [UTCDate]  AS (getutcdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Create an Access table, dbo_tblUTCDate,  linked via ODBC to the SQL table tblUTCDate.

Create an Access query to select from the Access table. I called it qryUTCDate.

```
SELECT dbo_tblUTCDate.UTCDate FROM dbo_tblUTCDate
```

In VBA:

```
Dim db as DAO.database, rs AS Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryUTCDate")
Debug.Print CStr(rs!UTCDATE)
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```