# Daylight Savings Handling in DateDiff() in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am fully aware of DateDiff()'s inability to handle daylight savings issues.  Since I often use it to compare the number of hours or days between 2 datetimes several months apart, I need to write up a solution to handle DST. This is what I came up with, a function that first subtracts 60 minutes from a datetime value if it falls within the date ranges specified in a local table (LU_DST). Thus, the usage would be:

```
 datediff("n",Conv_DST_to_Local([date1]),Conv_DST_to_Local([date2]))
```

My question is: Is there a better way to handle this? I'm going to make a wild guess that I'm not the first person with this question.  This seems like the kind of thing that should have been added to one of the core reference libraries.  Is there a way for me to access my system clock to ask it if DST was in effect at a certain date & time?

```
 Function Conv_DST_to_Local(X As Date) As Date
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("LU_DST")
    Conv_DST_to_Local = X
    While rst.EOF = False
        If X > rst.Fields(0) And X < rst.Fields(1) Then Conv_DST_to_Local = DateAdd("n", -60, X)
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
End Function
```

#### Notes

1. I have visited and imported the BAS file of http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx.  I spent at least an hour by now reading through it and, while it may do its job well, I can't figure out how to modify it to my needs.  But if you have an answer using his data structures, I'll take a look.
2. Timezones are not an issue since this is all local time.

#### Edit

Thanks for solutions, HansUp and Fenton, but I may be seeing a bug in the WbemScripting:

```
 Debug.Print Conv_date_to_Utc(#11/07/2009 02:15 PM#)
```

returns 11/7/2009 6:15:00 PM

```
 Debug.Print Conv_date_to_Utc(#11/08/2009 02:15 PM#)
```

returns 11/8/2009 7:15:00 PM

(I live in GMT-05:00).  Every website I can find is saying that the DST switch in November 2009 was on the 1st, not the 7th.  Why is this saying otherwise?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600875/how-to-get-the-current-datetime-in-utc-from-an-excel-vba-macro

Comment: Also consider the scenario where both date/times are on either side of a DST event.   That is January and December of the same year.  Or January and December two years apart.

Comment: Good thought, but both my solution and HansUp's solution bypass that issue by handling the 2 datetimes separately, subtracting the extra hour from both, or one, or neither, as needed.

Comment: Also WbemScripting seems to think DST began on 3/15 in 2009 instead of 3/8.  I'm sorry it is not reliable.

Comment: MS Access isn't really appropriate for professional developers. Sorry.. it doesn't have this functionality, SQL Server 2012 just got a lot of new timezone functionality!

Comment: @AaronKempf, depending on the project, Access may be ideal.  In this case, I just threw together a UDF to do it myself.

Comment: (but I cannot emphasize enough the word "Depending" in my last comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**: The method below does not return correct results for Daylight Saving Time transitions in U.S. for 2009.

Consider converting your date/time values to UTC before feeding them to DateDiff()

```
Public Function VT_DATE_to_UTC(ByVal pDate As Date) As Date
    Dim odateTime As Object
    Set odateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

    odateTime.SetVarDate pDate, True

    VT_DATE_to_UTC = odateTime.GetVarDate(False)
    Set odateTime = Nothing
End Function
```

An example in the Immediate Window:

```
? DateDiff("n", #2010/03/14 01:00#, #2010/03/14 03:00#)
 120 

? DateDiff("n", VT_DATE_to_UTC(#2010/03/14 01:00#), _
    VT_DATE_to_UTC(#2010/03/14 03:00#))
 60
```

Comment: +1 for short and to the point. It's significantly slower that the standard DateDiff, but I can work with that.

Comment: It could be speeded up if you didn't initialize the outside library every time you called the function -- make your object variable STATIC: Static odateTime As Object -- and initialize it only if it's Nothing (you'd probably want tear-down code for completenees, too, i.e., an optional parameter telling the function to set the object variable to Nothing).

Answer (score 2):

This is a refinement of @HansUp's solution, but more efficient if you call it multiple times, as it doesn't re-initialize and close the outside library each time it's called:

```
  Public Function VT_DATE_to_UTC(ByVal pDate As Date, _
       Optional bolCleanup As Boolean) As Date
    Static odateTime As Object

    If odateTime Is Nothing Then
       Set odateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
    ElseIf bolCleanup
       Set odateTime = Nothing
       Exit Function
    End If
    odateTime.SetVarDate pDate, True
    VT_DATE_to_UTC = odateTime.GetVarDate(False)
  End Function
```

This is will initialize the static variable the first time it's called and then re-use that object each time it's called until you call it with the optional argument set to True, which will close the external object.

Should you be using this object in more than one function, it would make more sense to define a standalone function that returns the object, and use that, instead:

```
  Public Function odateTime(Optional bolCleanup As Boolean) As Object
    Static objDateTime As Object

    If objDateTime Is Nothing Then
       Set objDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
    ElseIf bolCleanup
       Set objDateTime = Nothing
       Exit Function
    End If
    Set odateTime = objDateTime 
  End Function

  Public Function VT_DATE_to_UTC(ByVal pDate As Date) As Date
    odateTime.SetVarDate pDate, True
    VT_DATE_to_UTC = odateTime.GetVarDate(False)
  End Function
```

With this code, the first time you call the UTC function, it will initialize the date/time object (if it's not already initialized). And you'd clean up the object in your app's shutdown routine, with Call odateTime(True).

Comment: Whether to wrap in a class depends on what you're using it for. If you need to do a bunch of initialization of an object to use it, wrapping it in a class (with its Initialize event) is one way to do it. For something like this, I would see a class wrapper as overkill.

Answer (score 0):

(Original Poster here)

Thanks for the help, HansUp and Fenton.  I ended up using both of your suggestions to make a function that relies on Lotus Notes to convert to GMT for me.

Naturally, it's almost as bugged as the wbemscripting API thingy, but I made a workaround for one bug and the other isn't relevant (bugged for dates 2006 and earlier).

```
'Note: 1 minute is added to the NtDt to ensure the time component is created.  It is later subtracted.
Function ToGMT(ByVal X As Date) As Date
   Static NtSession As NotesSession
   If NtSession Is Nothing Then
       Set NtSession = New NotesSession
       NtSession.Initialize
   End If

   'Adjust for midnight
   Dim MidAdj As Boolean
   If TimeValue(X) = "12:00:00 AM" Then
       X = DateAdd("n", 1, X)
       MidAdj = vbTrue
   End If

   Dim NtDt As New NotesDateTime
   Set NtDt = NtSession.CreateDateTime(X)
   NtDt.ConvertToZone 5, True
   If MidAdj Then
      ToGMT = DateAdd("n", -1, CDate(NtDt.LSGMTTime))
   Else
      ToGMT = CDate(NtDt.LSGMTTime)
   End If
End Function
```

**EDIT:** This relies on Lotus Notes libraries so it won't be useful if you don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

Converto to UTC to work with dates - this would solve your DST problem as well as any future timezone problem that you may have.

Take the code that InteXX posted on the question below and paste it in a new module:
[How to get the current datetime in UTC from an Excel VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600875/how-to-get-the-current-datetime-in-utc-from-an-excel-vba-macro)

This has worked wonders for me in Microsoft Project.

Edit: Sorry I meant to give you this warning and forgot; don't use GMT, use UTC - https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html

Comment: Back then I found a Lotus Notes based solution that worked for me but I expect this will work for someone else.  And thanks for the FYI on GMT vs UTC.