# How do I get GMT time in Unix?

Tags: linux, date, unix, unix-timestamp

If my Unix machine is set to IST timezone, how can I get the current GMT time?

Comment: use the unix command in a one-liner that sets your timezone only for that command `TZ=gmt date`

Answer (score 81):

You can use the `-u` option of date command:

```
date -u
```

> -u    Display (or set) the date in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT-universal time), bypassing the normal conversion to (or from) local time.

Comment: Best way to print time in UTC with exporting TZ variable, date -u

Answer (score 40):

Like this with `date` shell command :

```
date -u
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing this from a shell script, you can use `date -u`, which gives you UTC.

From C, you would use `time()` in conjunction with `gmtime()` to give yourself a `struct tm` with the required data (`gmtime()` gives UTC, unlike `localtime()`).

Answer (score 6):

In command line, you can set a timezone to the one you would like to see, and check the time with date command, before returning to the original one.

```
#see current timezone
(date +%Z)

#change to a desired ie. London
export TZ=England/London

#or LA would be
export TZ=America/Los_Angeles

#check the time
date
```

Also of course, as suggested, to see just universal time, you can use the one suggested before