# How to find programatically the UTC offset for times in Document Properties of Excel binary (xls) format?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

We are talking about the old binary xls format here, Excel 2003 vintage.

The document properties appear to show the last modified time as the local time.

I want to convert to UTC.

We've tried the Aspose libraries.  They return DateTime.Kind = Unspecified.

We do not have the original file - just a byte array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current datetime in UTC from an Excel VBA macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600875/how-to-get-the-current-datetime-in-utc-from-an-excel-vba-macro)

Comment: not a duplicate: this is in C#.  Have added .net tag to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc`, or `FileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc`.  The type of file is not relevant.