# Trouble with Case - DateAdd function VBA

Tags: vba, case, dateadd

Case with DateAdd function.

Here is my code

```
Select Case Range("O7").Value

    Case "CST"
         Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11).Value = DateAdd("hh", -6, Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11))
    Case "EST"
         Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11).Value = DateAdd("hh", -5, Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11))
    Case "MST"
         Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11).Value = DateAdd("hh", -7, Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11))
    Case "PST"
         Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11).Value = DateAdd("hh", -8, Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11))
    Case Else
         Range(Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11)).Value = Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11)

End Select
```

Trying maniputlate date that is already present and change hrs from their time zone to UTC.  Thoughts on how to fix my code? "O7" houses list of CST,MST,EST, PST.  YZ, 11 is the date in current time zone.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600875/how-to-get-the-current-datetime-in-utc-from-an-excel-vba-macro

Comment: what is the format of your Sheet1.Cells(yz,11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax for `DateAdd()` is just one `"h"` to indicate hours.
Also, your last line is redundant... Remove `Range(Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11)).Value = Sheet1.Cells(yz, 11)`